# Too many magic rings and trinkets

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I am a DM, and I have two player's who love +1 Ac Rings, or any kind of ring or trinket to help with AC. Every bit of gold or other item of any value they use it to trade for it.

I try not to be mean about saying "hey, you can't have all these rings on" but they say back "nowhere does it say how many I can have. I have ten fingers for a reason."

Is there anywhere it says how many rings/trinkets you can have? And how can I stop the purchasing and finding of these rings without completely looking like the bad guy by controlling this?

Comment: Relevant, but in the context of opportunity attacks and feats, rather than magic items: [My group's misunderstood opportunity attacks for years; what to do now I know this?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/21432/1204)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Well first off, to answer your question about magic item limits, a character in 3.5e is limited to two magic rings. Found here: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rings.htm in the very first paragraph.

Second, AC bonuses do not stack unless they are different *types* of bonuses (armor, deflection, shield, etc.) or state that they stack. Usually, you cannot stack bonuses of the same type. Found here: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm

Third, to limit the buying of any item you could always add a bit of realism and force them to buy items at shops. Shops do not have unlimited supplies, therefore limiting the amount of any certain item they have. You are also not obligated to have the shop selling the item for what the book says is "list price."

Fourth. sit down and talk with your players about your concerns. Express how you wish to place limits without looking like the bad guy.

Comment: In regards to #3, it's worth noting that they could bypass a stock limitation with item creation feats. Rings of Protection +1 are very fast to create.

Comment: In response to tridus's comment, yes they can bypass limits with crafting. but that has its own costs like EXP and Money. Time and Materials. Time spent crafting is time spent not adventuring.

Answer (score 15):

As Novian's answer already mentioned, there are slot limits for items. You can't just wear ten magic rings.

If you want an easy way to visualize what those slot limits are, [the Magic Item Compendium had a special character sheet page just for magic items that lists the slots and what goes in them](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/MagicItemRecordSheet.zip). It's a really handy way to know what goes where and keep track of which slots are in use, and the sheet itself is free to download from Wizards even if you don't have that book.

Answer (score 3):

"A character can only **effectively** wear two magic rings. A third magic ring doesn’t work if the wearer is already wearing two magic rings."  This indicates that you **can** in fact wear more than two rings, but only the first two confer any bonus. (The feat Extra rings and a Hand of Glory can make it 5)

Answer (score 2):

Others have already mentioned that the rules limit you to two magical rings and that named bonuses don't stack but there may be other problems with the sudden rules clarification. If you've been letting the player get away with it for a while and he's invested a fair amount of money in magical rings of protection he might feel hard done by if he suddenly has a bunch of rings he can't use and wouldn't have bought if he'd known the rules at the time. You can do various things to alleviate the pain here.

Firstly, it's fairly simple to either let him convert the rings into a more powerful ring. You'll need to look at the cost of the rings to work this out but I think, off the top of my head, a Ring of Protection +1 cost 1,000gp and the +2 ring costs 4,000gp. He's not going to have as high an AC but he could trade four +1 rings for a +2 ring as if he's keen to keep his AC high he'd probably have upgraded if he'd know they didn't stack.

Secondly, if you want to bring this in to the game more and explain it through the story you could have the rings he's wearing start to cause problems as they interfere with each other. Maybe his AC starts getting a bit random, sometimes being higher than normal, sometimes penalising him. Alternatively the deflection aura could be greatly magnified, raising his AC by a ludicrous amount (+10 or so would probably work) but preventing him from getting anything close to him. He wouldn't be able to eat or drink with the rings on and, if he persists in wearing the rings he may find himself unable to breathe. This should encourage him to remove the items and look in to why his rings are having such problems leading right in to an adventure to find the old wizard Crimlock, an expert in magical item interference. Of course, he most likely lives far away from civilisation as the interference may cause problems. In fact, the players may have to save him from some problem of his own creation before he can help them by combining the rings in to the single, less powerful but more stable, Ring of Protection +2.

Depending on the player you may wish to talk to him about this before you start the quest line explaining why you are doing it. He may like the idea or he may prefer to just swap out the rings out of game and hand wave the mistake away. Either way works as long as everyone is happy and the game continues.

Comment: Good ideas. Another option is to let him sell the rings at full value, so that he can replace them with other items and not feel that he lost wealth in the outcome.

Answer (score -5):

Characters walking around with bling generally trust their bling to save them.  However bling cannot be worn at all times.  Characters cannot sleep in armor, nor can they take baths in all their bling.  When their bling is not on them, their bling can be stolen.

Pockets can be picked.  Necklaces can be cut off.  Thieves are inventive.  So are swindlers and con artists.  Another word for bling is "Thief Magnet".  Any group of characters walking into a town are tourists.  Tourists are fair game in any town.

Town gates are places of congestion.  An honest inn keeper will pay urchins and other people to guide tourists to their inns.  This form of guiding would include the guide picking up luggage, and leading horses towards the inn of their choice.  A dishonest guide will of course lose the tourist.

Smaller towns.... well, they'll steal you blind as well.  They might even way lay you on your way out of town.  Who would you complain to?

So, not only can you make it harder to get things by not having every town have everything, and use some of the suggestions above.  You can also infest your players with thieves of every variety and stripe.

Remember, thieves prosper :)

Comment: I see what you're getting at here (ways to eliminate too many magic items), but it doesn't really answer the question actually asked.

Comment: It does not answer the first, but it does answer the second.  The first question is answered in the rules.  You don't have to prevent players from doing what they want, however actions have consequences.

Comment: Oh, you mean the *"how can I stop the purchasing and finding of these rings without completely looking like the bad guy by controlling this?"* part. Then I just disagree: Players hate having their stuff taken away much more than they dislike DMs maintaining control over what gets into their hands in the first place.