# AoOs against the same enemy on his turn in 3.5?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I just read [this question on AoOs against the same enemy on his turn](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/41923/aoos-against-the-same-enemy-on-his-turn) and now I'm worried about my 3.5e build based on [this](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Inhuman_AoO-er_%283.5e_Optimized_Character_Build%29). Basically I combine high reach from inhuman and spiked chain, go into Thicket of Blades stance and add a couple more feats and other options that add AoO, so that you gain many AoOs against all opponents in range.

Now, I read the combat reflexes feat carefully, and I see:

> You can still make only one attack of opportunity per opportunity.

This is different than the pathfinder rule I saw. As far as I can tell: Every time you move out of a threatening square, I get a AoO on you (PHB):

> Provoking an Attack of Opportunity:Two kinds of actions can 
>   provoke attacks of opportunity: moving out of a threatened square 
>   and performing an action within a threatened square.

And since I have 20ft range, I get 3 before you stand next to me.

<s>Does PF really works different, or did I miss some rule?</s>

Edit: I just ran into this line from the P:

> Moving out of more than one square threatened by the same opponent in the same round doesn’t count as more than one opportunity for that opponent.

That does leave me with the questions:

1. Is movement the only action that trigger only one AoO when repeated during the same turn.
2. What about other things that effect AoO on movement like Thicket of Blades stance, does it apply to the same movement rule as above, or is it different?

   1. Would it give only 1 AoO, as there is only one movement.
   2. Would it give 2 AoO, one normal, and one for the stance.
   3. Would it give as many AoO as the opponent moves out of threatened squares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the rule you quoted

> Moving out of more than one square threatened by the same opponent in the same round doesn't count as more than one opportunity for that opponent.

is specific to movement, clarifying that moving out of a threatened square is considered one provocation. Should an enemy perform (or attempt to perform) the same provoking maneuver twice in a round (such as trying to stand up twice), you get two attacks of opportunity.

As for Thicket of Blades, it doesn't change the rule, it only broadens the conditions under which an AoO is provoked to include 5' steps and withdrawal (and *possibly* Tumbling). A character with Thicket of Blades still only gets one AoO against an enemy that moves normally out of a threatened square.